# What is the best hosting provider for MongoDB on windows?

Tags: mongodb, web-hosting

I am looking for reliable hosting provider for MongoDB.
I need to host on Windows OS with dedicated server.
I am not seeing any named player that offers mongo hosting.
Hope you guys can help me with this.

My budget $100 max per month.
Thanks

Comment: Can't you google "mongodb hosting" ?

Comment: Three upvote for a google-this-for-me question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hosting+Center

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this question is best for stackoverflow, but ...

If you want a "dedicated server" you aren't gonna get it for $100 a month :) ... but you can get close: I'd suggest a VPS, with plenty of RAM.

With a [Virtual Private Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) (VPS) you get a whole "virtual" OS install to yourself, to do whatever you want.

You can install MongoDB (that's where the RAM comes in) and do whatever you need to do yourself, host multiple domains, install Windows services, etc.

I've used both of these personally ...

- http://www.kickassvps.com/
- http://www.automatedvps.com/

Both with Windows + MongoDB and it's worked great.

Of course, you'll need to know how to admin a Windows machine ...

Comment: $100 is quite good amount of money. Plus the database is free. I am exploring. I don't want vps. thx fot the links.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet might be a cloud server from [Rackspace Cloud](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/) or [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).  I've run MongoDB on both providers, on Windows and Linux, with no problems.

Around your price range of $100 per month you can get a Windows box with these specs:

- Rackspace: 2GB RAM, 80GB HD, 32 or 64-bit ($116.80/month)
- Amazon EC2: 1.7GB RAM, 160 GB HD, 32-bit ($87.60/month)

In that price range, I'd be tempted to go with Rackspace because of the 64-bit Windows option, although you could also look into EC2 Micro instances using EBS, which have a 64-bit option.

If you're running MongoDB on a 32-bit system then you're database size is limited to about 2GB, so it's usually best avoided.

Comment: +1 for new info. I will be on 64 bit OS. EC2 seems better. It has double HD but 32 bit.